# Update a model field when another modal field is updated

Tags: django, django-models

Having two models:

```
class A(models.Model):
    project_code = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False, blank=False)
    reference_code = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    quantity = models.CharField(
        max_length=250,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )


class B(models.Model):
    project_id = models.IntegerField(
        null=False, 
        blank=False, 
        default=0,
    )
    quantity = models.CharField(
        max_length=250,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
```

I would like to update `B.quantity` when `A.quantity` changes. How could I synchronize the two fields?

When creating a `B` object, `B.quantity` always gets the value from existing `A.quantity`.

I have been researching and [found this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) in the official documentation, but it is not clear to me how to 'synchronize' `Many-to-one relationships` with a single field since it seems to synchronize the entire table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override save method of A model. You can also achieve it using django signals, but it's more convenient and clear to override the save method.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().save(args, kwargs)
    B.objects.filter(<relation_field>).update(quantity=self.quantity)
```

Comment: Can you explain please, why overriding save method more convenient and clear than using pre_save/post_save signals?